# Hotkeys creation for java swing form

Tags: java, swing, key-events

How to Create hot keys for form which is made by java swing?for example the form is create for  student details means if I press ALT+N means the cursor will goto that name entering field.ALT+R means the cursor will goto Reg.no entering Field.same like as mark1(m1),mark(2) and so on.At that same time the form contains save,exit buttons if I press CTRL+S means the Save button will select.CTRL+X means the exit button will select.how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), then use that knowledge in conjunction with [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29).

---

> CTRL+X means the exit button will select.

See also [`setMnemonic(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic%28char%29) for buttons and [`setAccelerator(KeyStroke)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator%28javax.swing.KeyStroke%29) for menu items.  Or more generally, constructing those controls using an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) that has the values configured.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the following link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html
It might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

> means if I press ALT+N means the cursor will goto that name entering field

This is generally done by using JLabel/JTextField pairs. Something like:

```
JLabel firstNameLabel = new JLabel("First Name");
JTextField firstNameTextField(15);
firstNameLabel.setLabelFor( firstNameTextField );
firstNameLabel.setDisplayedMnemonic( 'F' );
panel.add( firstNameLabel );
panel.add( firstNameTextField );
```

Then using Alt-F will set focus on the text field.

The Key Bindings will be done automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks!  My learn item for the day.  I don't know how I could have missed that method for associating a label with an input control.  Brilliant.  I'm busy playing with it now.  :-)